# How to increase the salt length of crypt PHP API with CRYPT_SHA512?

Tags: php, security, authentication, passwords, crypt

```
<?php

  echo 'SHA-512:' . crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$6$rounds=5000$usesomesillystringforsalt$');
```

**Output:**
`SHA-512: $6$rounds=5000$usesomesillystri$D4IrlXatmP7rx3P3InaxBeoomnAihCKRVQP22JZ6EY47Wc6BkroIuUUBOov1i.S5KPgErtP/EN5mcO.ChWQW21`

It uses only 16 character salt : *usesomesillystri*

**Refs:** [crypt — One-way string hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

**Question:**

- Is it possible to increase the salt length?
- Is there any drawback if we increase the salt length?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The docs at http://php.net/crypt would seem to indicate it's not possible. "SHA-512 hash with a sixteen character salt..." 16 should be plenty.

Comment: Is there any drawback if we increase the salt length?

Comment: You mean other than "it won't work"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two questions immediately come to mind:

1. Why are you using `CRYPT_SHA512` instead of `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`?
2. Why are you using `crypt()` instead of `password_hash()`/`password_verify()`/`password_needs_rehash()`?

One of the reasons you should use `password_*` instead of `crypt()` is it will generate a unique random salt for you. You really don't want to hand-roll your own salt generator if your goal is to be secure.

> Is it possible to increase the salt length?

SHA512Crypt only allows a 16-character salt. Bcrypt uses a 22-character salt (a base64-encoded representation of a 128-bit random string).

Let's quantify this: A 128-bit salt (powered by a CSPRNG) will repeat exactly once (with 50% probability) after 2^64 (1.8446744e+19, or **18,446,744,073,709,551,616**) password hashes are generated.

That's about 2.6 billion bcrypt hashes for **every living person on planet Earth**.

You don't *need* a longer salt for any appreciable security gain.

> Is there any drawback if we increase the salt length?

It will silently truncate and, while you may feel smart for seemingly using a longer salt, it will have no effect on the security.

Further reading: [How to safely store your users' passwords in 2016](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016).